# What test frameworks can be used when doing Selenium based automation in C# for functional tests?

Tags: selenium, c#

I have done some research and found that most frameworks available are either for unit testing or the work on them has stopped. I need to either build or find a suitable testing framework for functional testing that will have capabilities to take screenshots, write logs and manage test runs.

Our company has just started test automation hence I can not choose frameworks whose maintenance has come to halt. We are small setup so going for Proprietary options are also very limited.

Comment: I'm truly sorry but I feel this is far too broad to attract great answers. Perhaps if we could narrow the scope of the question a little we could revisit it, but I highly suspect that won't be the case.

Comment: @corsiKa Don't agree, OP simply has (had) the misconception that unit testing frameworks cannot be used for Selenium. In practice though, the two I gave in my answer are probably the only ones used for C# Selenium;

Comment: @corsiKa I think my intent is clear as FDM pointed out. I want to find out a functional testing framework that is written for people doing selenium based automation in C#. I do not see much scope for improvement but would appreciate if you can update with suggestions.

Comment: Alrighty, I'll go along with that. It's a little iffy; the major thing is FDM's comment that he's essentially exhausted the list of candidate frameworks. In general, questions that are "of all the ones I could use, which should I use" are too broad of questions. If all is two, then, I guess situtationally, it's not the end of the world. Still think I got it right by the book, but I'll let it go ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with Visual Studio Community?

It's free, perfect for C# and has the Microsoft UnitTest framework integrated.
And if you don't like that one, use NUnit (also free).

Comment: I have worked a bit with Microsoft UnitTest but not nUnit. I am not writing Unit tests but functional tests using selenium. Can these framework work in these scenarios?

Comment: Yes. Most Selenium Frameworks in C# use one of both. See for example the official Selenium tests, they use nUnit: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/dotnet/test

Comment: My own framework currently uses MS UnitTest and it's fine as well.